# Syntax error regarding line 15 characters 27-34 in an OCaml tree search function

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I wrote the function below to look through a tree and return a list in increasing order that contains all the indexes/subscripts of even elements in the tree. However I am getting a syntax error at the line `let rec GetSubEvenGen tree counter list =`  about the argument counter. When prompting chat GPT about this it failed to spot any errors. I'd appreciate any advice on why a syntax error is being raised.

```
 type 'a tree = 
  |Lf 
  |Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;; 

exception Subscript
let rec look = function
  | Lf, _ -> raise Subscript 
  | Br (v, t1, t2), k ->
      if k = 1 then v
      else if k mod 2 = 0 then
        look (t1, k / 2)
      else
        look (t2, k / 2);; 

let rec GetSubEvenGen tree counter list = 
  try
    let element = look (tree, counter) in
    if element mod 2 = 0 then
      GetSubEvenGen tree (counter + 1) (element::list)
    else
      GetSubEvenGen tree (counter + 1) (list)
  with 
    Subscript -> List.rev(list);;

let getSubsOfEvens tree = GetSubEvenGen tree 1 [];;
```

I tried running this code, I expected it to be syntactically correct, however a syntax error was raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function names in OCaml must begin with lowercase letters. Your `GetSubEvenGen` name causes the syntax error.

Fixing this, your code compiles without issue:

```
# type 'a tree =
    | Lf
    | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree

  exception Subscript

  let rec look = function
    | Lf, _ -> raise Subscript
    | Br (v, t1, t2), k ->
      if k = 1 then v
      else if k mod 2 = 0 then
        look (t1, k / 2)
      else
        look (t2, k / 2)

  let rec getSubEvenGen tree counter list =
    try
      let element = look (tree, counter) in
      if element mod 2 = 0 then
        getSubEvenGen tree (counter + 1) (element::list)
      else
        getSubEvenGen tree (counter + 1) (list)
    with
      Subscript -> List.rev(list)

  let getSubsOfEvens tree = 
    getSubEvenGen tree 1 [];;
type 'a tree = Lf | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
exception Subscript
val look : 'a tree * int -> 'a = <fun>
val getSubEvenGen : int tree -> int -> int list -> int list = <fun>
val getSubsOfEvens : int tree -> int list = <fun>
```